# How to get sourcemaps for gulp+babel+browserify+uglify

Tags: gulp, browserify, babeljs, uglifyjs

I am using gulp to bundle browserify+babelify with uglifyjs. O
However, the sourcemaps generated from my project only give me the bundled version, not the bundled version.

Here is my setup:

```
var gulp       = require('gulp'),
    source     = require('vinyl-source-stream'),
    browserify = require('browserify'),
    gutil      = require('gulp-util'),
    buffer     = require('vinyl-buffer'),
    sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps'),
    uglify     = require('gulp-uglify'),
    file       = 'index.js';

gulp.task('build', function(){
    return browserify({
        entries: [file],
        transform: ["babelify"]
      })
    .bundle()
    .pipe(source(file))
    .pipe(buffer())
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init({loadMaps: true}))
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/js'))
    .pipe(gutil.noop())
})
```

Is there a way for me to create a build that bundles babel=>browserify=>uglify and still return me maps to my pre-babel files?

I also don't mind not using gulp (I actually prefer grunt but this setup used to work for me in the past).

Comment: Hi, Why a `gutil.noop() ` at the end ?

Comment: The question states `only give me the bundled version, not the bundled version`.  I'm assuming you mean `only give me the bundled version` **and not the *unbundled* version**.  If so can you make the edit to update the question.

Comment: My guess is that the `gutil.noop()` was added in an attempt to make another gulp task *wait* for the `gulp.dest()` to complete.  But I don't think gulp works that way.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First of all you need to set browserify to generate source maps by setting the debug option to true, then if you want the pre babelify source maps you need to configure babelify to generate source maps:

```
   var gulp       = require('gulp'),
    source     = require('vinyl-source-stream'),
    browserify = require('browserify'),
    gutil      = require('gulp-util'),
    buffer     = require('vinyl-buffer'),
    sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps'),
    uglify     = require('gulp-uglify'),
    babelify   = require('babelify')
    file       = 'index.js';

gulp.task('build', function(){
    return browserify(file,{debug:true}).transform(babelify, {presets: ["es2015", "react"],sourceMaps:true})
    .bundle()
    .pipe(source(file))
    .pipe(buffer())
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init({loadMaps: true}))
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/js'))
    .pipe(gutil.noop())
})
```

Comment: I did this, but I am not able to put breakpoints in chrome debugger on some lines. Mostly on the lines that are not scoped in a function. Any tips for this?

Comment: I've found that passing `{ compress: false }` to `uglify()` fixes some odd breakpoint behavior in Chrome.

Comment: I would not run `uglify()` at all when creating source maps.